# Android - JSON parsing without the array name using Retrofit

Tags: json, arraylist, retrofit2

I have json respose with no arrayname.

Below are the code till now I have done.

JSON Response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 101,
            "name": "abc",
        "number": 1234567890
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
            "user_id": 102,
         "name": "xyzzy",
         "number": 8888888888
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 103,
        "name":"sdfdsdv",
        "number": 2222222222
    }
]
```

Interface Class

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("user/details”)
Call<List<User_List>> getUser(
        @Query(“id”)String id
);
}
```

User_List Class

```
public class User_List {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    int id;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    int user_id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    String name;
    @SerializedName("number")
    @Expose
    Int number;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

MainActivity Class

```
Public void fetch() {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<User_List>> user = apiInterface.getUser(id);

        user(new Callback<List<user_List>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<user_List>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<user_List>> response) {
                try{


                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < user_list(); i++) {
                            int id = user_list.get(i).getId();
               String name = user_list.get(i).getName();
                        }
                    }else {

                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ProductEnquiry_Contributor>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
```

I tried to parse it but can't find success,Can anyone suggest me how to parse this type of Response using Retrofit?

It gives me failure in response
Error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this

```
 @POST("endpoint)
    Call<List<yourPOJO> methodname(@Body BodyPOJO bodyPojo);
```

or

```
@POST("endpoint)
        Call<Response<List<yourPOJO>> methodname(@Body BodyPOJO bodyPojo);
```

Comment: you should get your list from body()...... also print error in onFailure   t.printStackTrace(); to identify error if any